# print index and do logic in list comprehension

Tags: python, indexing, list-comprehension

I have a really large list and while processing it I want to know which index I am on during the process.

A simple example:

```
l = ['a','b','c']
[ print(i), char.capitalize() for i,char in enumerate(l)]
```

But here `i` is not defined. Is it possible to print and run some logic in list comprehension?

Update: Seems normal for loop is the way. fyi, my motivation is to use `asyncio.gather`, for which I've only seen examples in list comprehension, e.g.

```
async def gather():
    await asyncio.gather(*[slowtask() for _ in range(10)])
```

Comment: Try `[ (print(i), char.capitalize()) for i,char in enumerate(l)]`. Note that this will add a `None` to every item in the list of tuples. If you don't want that, consider doing a normal for loop. It's perfectly suitable for this.

Comment: if your list is really large as you mention it won't be wise to use a comprehension list that adds unnecessary `None`. Use a regular `for i, elem in enumerate(l):` loop

Comment: `[char.capitalize() for i,char in enumerate(l) if not print(i)]` will do it, but it's a hack. List comprehensions aren't for this sort of thing. A for loop should be preferred in this case.

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension for side effects, use a normal loop.

Comment: A `for-loop` is more appropriate as all agreed here...  Strange Use case.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I guess I left out the motivation - wanted to see if I can do this for `asyncio.gather` which from what I've seen is works with list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

All of the comment are good but you must consider that print function is an "io" operation in operation systems and is very slow. If your list is too big, this function make your code very slow.
I think that because of long runtime you want to see the index of your list.
If it is true, I advise you to use from pandas package. Convert your list to a pandas series and use from pandas methods for your computation. Pandas is very very fast and optimize your computation.